# Error when deploying .sppkg file to SharePoint App Catalog

Tags: sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have been following [this tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part), and I have been having a bit of trouble deploying the app to the App Catalog in my Office 365 SP-Online tenant.

I decided to go back and start again, but this time rather than adding the extra functionality the tutorial goes through, I would just keep it really simple and try and deploy the basic app that is generated when I run `yo @microsoft/sharepoint` in PowerShell (surely this would just work 'as is').

I run `gulp package-solution` and upload the .sppkg file to my App Catalog, SP asks me whether 'I trust the app', I say 'Yes' and click 'Deploy'. I then get the below error message in the 'App Package Error Message' Column.

> Deployment failed.  Correlation ID: 0382f19e-3074-0000-a490-b4c1f2311f84

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Wetransfer Link to package-solution.json file:
https://we.tl/t-cc1pG7hjAk

Comment: Can you post your package-solution.json file

Comment: Ok, just updated the question with a download link. Thanks!

Comment: please post your json file...

Comment: also do you have any error while packaging solution?

Comment: Which JSON file do you require? Also, PowerShell show's the following message; 'Warning - [package-solution] This is not a production build (--ship or --production), therefore the "includeClientSideAssets" setting will be ignored.', but that's the only 'error looking thing' it returns. Thanks!

Comment: /config/package-solution.json

Comment: @SiddharthVaghasia thanks! My post has been updated with a new download link for the package-solution.json file.